# How to Access CMake variables in CMakeLists.txt, through a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmake

I want to write a python script as a postbuild script, and I need to access the variables which are already defined in the `CMakeLists.txt` file. How can this be done?

Comment: You need to pass **values** of CMake variables as parameters to your python script. Alternatively, you could write *template* of a script, and pass it to the [configure_file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/configure_file.html): that way CMake produces the final script with CMake variables expanded.

Comment: when you say "postbuild", do you mean that the python script is called as a [build event registered via `add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events)?

Comment: yes, exactly. postbuild.py will be called via CmakeLists.txt